# The word "country" seems to often mean "sovereign state", including the UK. The UK identifies its component units as countries. Which sense is older?

Tags: meaning, history

I speak American English. My guess is that calling the UK a "country" would be seen as incorrect in British English. However, just about every map I see online showing "X by country" identifies the UK as one whole country, including those by the World Bank, Wikipedia, the CIA World Factbook...

Has the meaning shifted over time? What is the history of the word "country"?

Comment: In English, "country" is used to refer to the four *landen* of the Kingdom of the Netherlands (the European Netherlands, Aruba, etc), as well as the countries of the UK, but it doesn't seem to be used for many nations' subnational divisions.

Comment: *Has the meaning shifted over time?* No. It has always been vague and context-dependent. https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=country

Comment: There are also the terms ["home nation" and "home country"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Nations) (for England, Wales, Scotland, and N. Ireland). Whether that clarifies or confuses things is unclear to me!

Answer (score 4):

The history of the word "country" is a research project, first published as *A New English Dictionary on Historical Principles; Founded Mainly on the Materials Collected by The Philological Society*, not just known as the *Oxford English Dictionary*. Originally, the word, from Middle French (meaning region, area of land delimited by natural or political boundaries) was used in a broader sense, as they say (sense 1) "The land of a person's birth, citizenship, residence, etc.; one's homeland", or (sense 2) "Land, terrain, or a region of undefined extent, esp. considered with regard to its physical characteristics" such as chalk country, fen country, stag-hunting country, country of the red deer. The latter use is fairly common in American English. I do not think the meaning has changed much over time, instead, politics has changed.

Comment: In the US, _the country_ means _not the city_.

Comment: It does in the UK as well.

Comment: @John Lawler: But not exclusively: Biden lays out vision for the country, as political divisions growhttps://www.youtube.com › watch President Joe Biden delivered his first State of the Union address ... Biden lays out vision for the country, as political divisions grow

Comment: As noted by the OP, it also has a political sense.

Comment: It is not clear how this is supposed to answer the question. Neither of the quoted definitions captures the sense in which the four countries of the UK are countries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can call the UK a country, judging by this sentence from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom):

> The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, commonly known as the United Kingdom (UK) or Britain,[note 1][19] is a sovereign country in Europe....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139472/discussion-on-answer-by-aparente001-the-word-country-seems-to-often-mean-sove).